# Inno Setup - Delete old/obsolete files on update

Tags: inno-setup

So, I realize that this question has been asked before. In fact I read through a good 10 of them before writing this, but none of them have a applicable solution and I'm hoping that nowadays someone has found something.

The problem:
My program is build with a script, creating all final files in a single folder.
Those files are included in inno like this:

```
[Files]
Source: "build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\*"; Excludes: "*.key, *.log"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

The application has been out there for a few months with different updates. There is no record anymore of old files, though it could be painstakingly re-assembled as we do have version control and I could build the old installers again.

From what I understand, you're meant to use the `InstallDelete` section to get rid of old files - however you are not meant to use wildcards and there is also no `Excludes` section to safeguard the single folder we have that may contain user data they may want to keep.

So, how do I get rid of old files? The application is 100 MB and a current user may have 300+ MB of old files that are no longer necessary, I'd love to clean that up.

**TL;DR:** I want the installer to either overwrite or delete all files in the application directory, except for one folder which contains user data.

Comment: So you want to delete all files from the installation folder that were not installed by the update installer?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. I added a summary at the end to clarify this.

Comment: While the linked *question* is about uninstallation, the code in the *answer* can be used in installer too.

Comment: Seems like it would first delete everything, then write everything. Would be nice if only stuff gets deleted that won't get overwritten anyway.

Comment: That matters only, if you use flags that prevent overwritting an existing files if they exist already. If you overwrite files unconditionaly, I do not see any difference.

Comment: Less Harddrive / SSD strain, for example.

Comment: Why? If you are overwritting the files anyway?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: No, as the solution was deployed on 2nd of july; we simply included a small exe to be run at the end of setup that compares a manifest file that we send with, anything not in manifest gets deleted and anything in manifest gets checksum checked - might as well. I wasn't able to answer the question myself as it was marked duplicate and that apparently makes that impossible so I moved on with my life.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to delete all files in the installation folder before the installation.

As you know, you can use [`[InstallDelete]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installdeletesection) for that. But that does not allow you to exclude the "data" folder.

You can code that Pascal Scripting instead. See [Inno Setup - Delete whole application folder except for data subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36491213/850848). You can call the `DelTreeExceptSavesDir` function from my answer to the that question from [`CurStepChanged(ssInstall)`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) event function:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    DelTreeExceptSavesDir(WizardDirValue); 
  end;
end;
```

---

If you really want to delete only obsolete files, to avoid deleting and re-creating existing files (what's *not your case*, as you are using `ignoreversion` flag anyway), you can use preprocessor to generate a list of files to be installed for the Pascal Scripting and use that to delete only really obsolete files.

```pascal
#pragma parseroption -p-

#define FileEntry(DestDir) \
    "  FilesNotToBeDeleted.Add('" + LowerCase(DestDir) + "');\n"

#define ProcessFile(Source, Dest, FindResult, FindHandle) \
    FindResult \
        ? \
            Local[0] = FindGetFileName(FindHandle), \
            Local[1] = Source + "\\" + Local[0], \
            Local[2] = Dest + "\\" + Local[0], \
            (Local[0] != "." && Local[0] != ".." \
                ? FileEntry(Local[2]) + \
                  (DirExists(Local[1]) ? ProcessFolder(Local[1], Local[2]) : "") \
                : "") + \
            ProcessFile(Source, Dest, FindNext(FindHandle), FindHandle) \
        : \
            ""

#define ProcessFolder(Source, Dest) \
    Local[0] = FindFirst(Source + "\\*", faAnyFile), \
    ProcessFile(Source, Dest, Local[0], Local[0])

#pragma parseroption -p+

[Code]

var
  FilesNotToBeDeleted: TStringList;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  FilesNotToBeDeleted := TStringList.Create;
  FilesNotToBeDeleted.Add('\data');
  {#Trim(ProcessFolder('build\exe.win-amd64-3.6', ''))}
  FilesNotToBeDeleted.Sorted := True;

  Result := True;
end;

procedure DeleteObsoleteFiles(Path: string; RelativePath: string);
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  FilePath: string;
  FileRelativePath: string;
begin
  if FindFirst(Path + '\*', FindRec) then
  begin
    try
      repeat
        if (FindRec.Name <> '.') and (FindRec.Name <> '..') then
        begin
          FilePath := Path + '\' + FindRec.Name;
          FileRelativePath := RelativePath + '\' + FindRec.Name;
          if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY <> 0 then
          begin
            DeleteObsoleteFiles(FilePath, FileRelativePath);
          end;

          if FilesNotToBeDeleted.IndexOf(Lowercase(FileRelativePath)) < 0 then
          begin
            if FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY <> 0 then
            begin
              if RemoveDir(FilePath) then
              begin
                Log(Format('Deleted obsolete directory %s', [FilePath]));
              end
                else
              begin
                Log(Format('Failed to delete obsolete directory %s', [FilePath]));
              end;
            end
              else
            begin
              if DeleteFile(FilePath) then
              begin
                Log(Format('Deleted obsolete file %s', [FilePath]));
              end
                else
              begin
                Log(Format('Failed to delete obsolete file %s', [FilePath]));
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      until not FindNext(FindRec);
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end;
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('Failed to list %s', [Path]));
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssInstall then
  begin
    Log('Looking for obsolete files...');
    DeleteObsoleteFiles(WizardDirValue, '');
  end;
end;
```

---

For other options, see [Inno Setup: Removing files installed by previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46007792/850848).