# How to remove files and folder Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I need to delete files from hard disk with Inno Setup.

We need to remove an old app version (not installed with Inno Setup), it was installed manually last year, and after remove old one, install the new one.

Some idea, Inno Setup script example? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`[InstallDelete]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=installdeletesection):

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{app}\*"
```

---

For more complicated cases, see also:
[Inno Setup - Delete old/obsolete files on update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51130059/850848)

Comment: There might be registry keys to delete too perhaps. The original poster has not said.